# What is total time in which Quran was completely revealed?

Tags: quran, revelation

Quran was revealed in approx 22 and a half years. Does anyone have the exact total time for this with a authentic source?

Comment: May I ask what is the value gained by such knowledge? How is this useful?

Comment: @mtk This still doesn't provide a rationale for spending time to research this subject. You already state that it took 22-23 years. Why would you spend time or effort to make this estimate more accurate? You could spend your time (and potential answerers' time) on something more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Qur'an and the tradition, scholars say that Qur'an was revealed twice.

Once, it was revealed in full at the night of Qadr. Although scholars have not reached a consensus as to its time and place.

Second time it was gradually revealed in a span of 23 years.

Comment: Please address the second question as well. Although OP should have asked it in another question.